# Highcharts X-axis labels on the side

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts, and I used to be able to get labels on the side. But it's not working now, am I missing something? The red arrow is where I would want the labels like in the following example.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

[image]

This is the code I'm using, I add the series in a dynamic way.

```
 credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
                labels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: {
                    text: 'Score',
                    align: 'high'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Add Series
        var detailchart = $('#chart-detail').highcharts();
        var categories = new Array;

        // Set Chart Title
        detailchart.setTitle({text: results[0].category});

        $.each(results, function(i, data){
            categories.push(data.name);
            detailchart.addSeries({
                name: data.name,
                data: [data.score]
            });
        });

        detailchart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["1", "2"]);
        $('#chart-detail').highcharts().reflow();
```

Results is an array that looks like this (I get it through ajax):

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference between your image and the JSFiddle you've linked? Looks the same to me.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I don't understand

Comment: The obvious thing I can see from your screenshots is that you only have data assigned to one category ("my commercial alertness"). That would explain why you have the four bars pegged to the same x-axis label. I'm also curious to know why you define a pair of categories in your chart options and then do so again further down in your code with `setCategories`. That **could** be why your label shows up as "0" and not the name as you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your code here, you wish to specify two categories with names 1 and 2 but you are not specifying any data for second category, So the only category that is showing on your chart is 1. Your data array for each series must have elements per each category. For example if you have two category you should consider having two data elements in each series. In this line ***data: [data.score]*** you are just specifying one element in data array. Your code should be something like this: (make it dynamic per your need)

```
$.each(results, function(i, data){
        categories.push(data.name);
        detailchart.addSeries({
            name: data.name,
            data: [data.score, 40], //40 is some data for your second category.
        });
    });
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/u6crkatv/

Comment: Thanks for answering after over 3 years haha.

Comment: I didn't check the date realy :D Anyway I hope it will help someone with same problem.

Comment: Haha I'm sure it will. Thanks for the trip down codememory lane.

Answer (score 0):

Only what you need is use 4 series, each of them with single data point.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [138]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973]
    },{
        name: 'Year 20098',
        data: [973]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9wzggc4/

Comment: This is also showing just zero in the sidebar on the left? Not the name? Thanks!